# Verilog source code for MIPS

Tags: mips, verilog, fpga

can anyone tell me about simple MIPS Verilog code without pipeline... its implementation on FPGA ?

regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various websites, like [OpenCores](http://www.opencores.org) which you can help you.